# Write stored procedure that returns value and table name and inserts value into table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ssms

I wrote a stored procedure in SQL Server 2019 which takes the table name and a value as parameters, and inserts that value into the defined table.

But when I try to run it, I get this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
> Incorrect syntax near 'ID'.

I want to respond with the `ID` of the newly inserted row, and `InsertedID`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertIn]
    @ItemTag nvarchar(max),
    @ItemString nvarchar(max),
    @InsertedID int = -1 OUTPUT,
    @InsertStatus bit = 0 OUTPUT
AS
    DECLARE @ActualTableName nvarchar(max)

    SELECT @ActualTableName = QUOTENAME(table_name) 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = @ItemTag

    DECLARE @ActualColumnName nvarchar(max)

    SELECT @ActualColumnName = QUOTENAME(column_name) 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = @ItemTag AND COLLATION_NAME = @ItemTag

    DECLARE @Count int = 0

    SET XACT_ABORT ON

    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        SET NOCOUNT ON
        DECLARE @CountSql nvarchar(max)

        SELECT @countSql =  'SELECT @Count = COUNT(*) FROM ' + @ActualTableName + ' WHERE '+ @ActualColumnName + ' = @ItemString ;'
        EXEC (countSql)

        IF @Count = 0
        BEGIN
            SET NOCOUNT ON;

            DECLARE @InsertSql nvarchar(max)
            DECLARE @InsertedIDSql nvarchar(max)

            SELECT @InsertSql = 'INSERT INTO' + @ActualTableName + '(' + @ActualColumnName + ') VALUES(' + @ItemString + ');' 
            SELECT @InsertedIDSql = 'MAX(ID) FROM' + @ActualTableName +';'

            EXEC(@InsertSql)
            EXEC(@InsertedIDSql)

            SET @InsertStatus = 1
        END
        ELSE 
            SET @InsertStatus = 0

        COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

I change it to this code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertIn]

    @ItemTag nvarchar(max),
    @ItemString nvarchar(max),
    @InsertedID int = -1 output,
    @InsertStatus bit = 0 output
    
AS
declare @ActualTableName nvarchar(max)
declare @ActualColumnName nvarchar(max)
    select @ActualTableName= QUOTENAME(table_name) from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_NAME = @ItemTag
    select  @ActualColumnName= QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = @ItemTag and COLUMN_NAME = @ItemTag

set xact_abort on
BEGIN transaction
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    declare @count int
    declare @CountSql nvarchar(max)
    select @countSql =  N'select @count = COUNT(*) from ' + @ActualTableName + N' where '+ @ActualColumnName+ N' = @ItemString ;';
    EXEC sp_executesql @countSql,N'@Count int OUTPUT, @ItemString nvarchar(max)',@Count = @Count OUTPUT,
        @ItemString = @ItemString;
if @Count = 0
    begin
        
        declare @InsertSql nvarchar(max)

        set @InsertSql =N'insert into '+ @ActualTableName + N' ('+@ActualColumnName+N') values(@ItemString)' ;
        exec sp_executesql @InsertSql,N'@ItemString nvarchar(max)',@ItemString = @ItemString;

        declare @InsertedIDSql nvarchar(max)
        set @InsertedIDSql = 'select @InsertedID=MAX(ID) from '+ @ActualTableName 
        exec sp_executesql @InsertedIDSql, N'@InsertedID int  output',@ItemString = @ItemString, @InsertedID = @InsertedID;
        set @InsertStatus = 1
    end
else
    set @InsertStatus = 0
        commit transaction
```

now i dont get error but it dosnt insert anything in table

Comment: Have you **looked** at your `@InsertSql` and `@InsertedIDSql` statements you're generating? I bet it's something like `INSERT INTOYourTableName(ColumnName).....` - that is **NOT** a valid SQL statement! (you need a space after the `INSERT INTO` and before the table name!). Also `@InsertedIDSql` is just `MAX(ID) FROMYourTableName` - again, SPACE is missing - and you don't have a `SELECT` or anything here either.....

Comment: Not to mention that `SELECT MAX(ID) ...` after an `INSERT` is ***NOT*** guaranteed to really return the last inserted value (one or more other connections might have inserted their values in the meantime) - use something like `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` (if you're using an `INT IDENTITY` column) or some other means to **really** get the value inserted....

Comment: @marc_s  i Change my code but it dosnt work too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i change code to this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertIn]

    @ItemTag nvarchar(max),
    @ItemString nvarchar(max),
    @InsertedID int = -1 output,
    @InsertStatus bit = 0 output
AS
declare @ActualTableName nvarchar(max)
declare @ActualColumnName nvarchar(max)
    select @ActualTableName= QUOTENAME(table_name) from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_NAME = @ItemTag
    select  @ActualColumnName= QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = @ItemTag and COLUMN_NAME = @ItemTag

set xact_abort on
BEGIN transaction
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    declare @Count int
    declare @CountSql nvarchar(max)
    set @countSql =  N'select @Count = COUNT(*) from ' + @ActualTableName + N' where '+ @ActualColumnName+ N' = @ItemString ;'
    exec sp_executesql @countSql,
    N'@Count int output, @ItemString nvarchar(max)',
    @Count = @Count output, @ItemString = @ItemString

if @Count = 0
    begin
        declare @InsertQuery nvarchar(max)
        set @InsertQuery ='insert into '+ @ActualTableName + '('+@ActualColumnName+') values(@ItemString);' 
        exec sp_executesql @InsertQuery,
        N'@ItemString nvarchar(max)',
        @ItemString = @ItemString;

        declare @InseredIDQuery nvarchar(max)
        set @InseredIDQuery =N'select @InsertedID=max(ID) from '+ @ActualTableName +';'
        exec sp_executesql @InseredIDQuery,
        N'@InsertedID int output',
        @InsertedID = @InsertedID

        set @InsertStatus = 1
    end
else
    set @InsertStatus = 0
    commit transaction
```

and work fine

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).